# Including external assembly functions from a .asm file into a .h C header file

Tags: c, assembly, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a C header file `cpu_checks.h` that declares an `extern` function, which is implemented in an assembly file `cpu.asm`.

cpu_checks.h:

```c
#ifndef CPU_CHECKS_H
#define CPU_CHECKS_H 

extern int is_cpuid_available(void);

// Some more functions . . .

#endif
```

cpu.asm:

```asm
section .text
        global is_cpuid_available

is_cpuid_available:
    ; implementation . . .
    ret
```

Makefile:

```make
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=n
KDIR ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

DRIVER_DIR=path/to/driver/dir

MY_CFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG
ccflags-y += ${MY_CFLAGS}
CC += ${MY_CFLAGS}
NASM=nasm
NASMFLAGS=-f elf64 -F stabs

obj-m := hyper.o
hyper-objs := $(DRIVER_DIR)/entry.o $(DRIVER_DIR)/cpu_checks.o $(DRIVER_DIR)/cpu.o

cpu.o: $(DRIVER_DIR)/cpu.asm
    $(NASM) $(NASMFLAGS) $(DRIVER_DIR)/cpu.asm

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD

install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD modules_install

debug:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules 
    EXTRA_CFLAGS="$(MY_CFLAGS)"

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD clean
```

Compiling works but the `is_cpuid_available` function is still an unresolved symbol, so I'm guessing that the file is unlinked or unincluded, but I do not know how to include the .asm file inside the .h header file.
How is that possible to include my assembly functions from my .asm file inside my C header file?

Comment: Your code looks correct, I suppose your build script might not include `cpu.o` in the kernel module.  Unfortunately I am not familiar with the build process and your code is not a [mcve] so I cannot investigate myself.

Comment: Does `$(DRIVER_DIR)/cpu.o` actually get built? The Makefile has a rule for building `cpu.o`.

Comment: @IanAbbott yes it does. Since the cpu.o needs to be built with $(NASM) and not $(CC) I made a distinguished rule for it.

Comment: Unless `$(DRIVER_DIR)` is `.`, building of the file `$(DRIVER_DIR)/cpu.o` does NOT use rule `cpu.o: $(DRIVER_DIR)/cpu.asm`. You probably want `$(DRIVER_DIR)/cpu.o: $(DRIVER_DIR)/cpu.asm` rule instead.

Comment: And you should check `nasm` behavior. If, by default, it creates the object file in the current directory, modify your recipe and add the `-o $@` option: `$(NASM) $(NASMFLAGS) -o $@ $<` such that it creates the object file in the `$(DRIVER_DIR)` directory.